# When is an AngularJS service re-initialized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

What is the lifecycle of a service (or factory) in angularjs and when is it re-initialzed ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Angular bootstraps, it attaches the constructor functions for services to the associated module. This happens once.

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .service('User', function UserConstructor() {
    // stuff
  });
```

---

When a you try to run a controller or something that depends on a certain service, Angular will inject it for you.

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function FirstCtrlConstructor(User) {
  // User is available here
});
```

Under the hood, angular uses this thing called `$injector` to do dependency injection for you. It works something like this:

```
var $injector = {};
$injector.cached = [];
$injector.get = function(service) {
  // check if service is in this.cached
    // if so, return it
    // if not
      // 1) instantiate the service
      // 2) store it in this.cached
      // 3) return it
};
```

So when Angular sees that it needs to inject `User` into `FirstCtrlConstructor`, it calls `$injector.get('User')` to get the `User`. Since it hasn't injected `User` anywhere else before, it'll hit the "if not" condition and:

1. Call `new User()`.
2. Store it in `$injector.cached` for next time.
3. Return it.

Now let's say that we need to inject `User` a second time:

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function SecondCtrlConstructor(User) {
  // stuff
});
```

Again, when Angular sees that `SecondCtrlConstructor` depends on `User`, it calls `$injector.get('User')` to get the `User` so it could inject it. This time, it hits the "if so" condition. Since we previously put `User` in `$injector.cached`, it found it there for us. Thus, `User` doesn't get instantiated again.

Say we have a `ThirdCtrl` that also depends on `User`. It too would find it in `$injector.cached`, and so it wouldn't instantiate `UserConstructor`. Say that we have `myDirective` that depends on `User`. The same thing would happen - it'd find it in `$injector.cached` and thus wouldn't instantiate it.

This is called the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It's used when you don't want to instantiate something more than once. Angular uses this for services so they don't get instantiated more than once. The same is true for factories (and probably also true for providers; probably not true for values and constants).

See https://medium.com/@adamzerner/dependency-injection-in-angular-18490a9a934 for some more info.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome explanation.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 6):

Services/factories are only initialized once, the first time they are used. From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

> Angular services are:
>
> - Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an
>     application component depends on it.
> - Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
>     generated by the service factory.